# Calling multiple outbound call from Vert.x

Tags: java, asynchronous, vert.x

I am using Spring MVC controllers today for end clients to invoke and do processing and having outbound network calls.
The operations are all sequential today, and for requirement #2 can only happen after #1, but individual #2 calls can happen in parallel.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/callme", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MyResponse processMe(@RequestBody MyRequest myrequest, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    //do some computation

    // call end point 1 -------> #1

    //do some more computation

    for(int i = 0; i< n; i++) {
        // call end point 2 with different body ------->#2
    }

    //process request

    //set http response status code

    //return MyResponse

}
```

To solve this kind of problem to avoid the main thread always waiting, Vertx.io seems like a positive direction, however I am stuck implementing #1 itself.

Issues :

## 1. SEVERE: Unexpected exception in route

java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must set the Content-Length header to be the total size of the message body BEFORE sending any data if you are not using HTTP chunked encoding.

## 2. How do I implement calling multiple #2 calls as part of callback?

Here is my Vert.x code

```
private void callMe(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    final MyObj MyObj = Json.decodeValue(routingContext.getBodyAsString(),
        MyObj.class);


    HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient(options);


    HttpClientRequest request = client.post("<URL>" + MyObj.getCustomerId(), response -> {
        callback(response);

    }) ;

    // Now do stuff with the request


    request.putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
    request.putHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
    request.write(routingContext.getBodyAsString());

    // Make sure the request is ended when you're done with it
    request.end();



    routingContext.response()
        .setStatusCode(200)
        .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        .end(Json.encodePrettily(uploadUrl));

}

private void callback(HttpClientResponse response) {
    System.out.println("received response: " + response.statusMessage());

    int code = response.statusCode();
    if (code == 200) {
        
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1/ Using the client

The `IllegalStateException` message explains the problem: if you're not using chunked encoding for transfer, you must set the content length of the payload before sending data (as required by web standards):

```
request.putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, contentSize);
```

Or, instead of invoking `request.write(content)` then `request.end()`, you can simply invoke `request.end(content)`. In this case, Vert.x will compute the content length header for you.

Note that the Vert.x team does not recommend to use the low-level `HttpClient`. This is for advanced use cases. Take a look at the `WebClient`, it's much easier to deal with: [vertx-web-client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/)

2/ Parallel processing

There are different solutions to combine results from requests processed in parallel. The builtin solution is to use Vert.x `Future` instead of callbacks for your WebClient calls and then [concurrent composition](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_concurrent_composition):

```
CompositeFuture.all(Arrays.asList(future1, future2, future3));
```

Otherwise you can try RxJava.